# Adding HTML code to the text attribute of appendTo function

Tags: jquery, html

I want to display the following html code in jQuery :

```
<a title="Linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank">
 <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
   <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x linkedincolor"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x"></i>
 </span>
</a>
```

I'm blocking with this current JQuery code :

```
$('<a>',{
  text: '<span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x linkedincolor"></i><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x"></i></span>',
  title: 'Linkedin',
  href: 'https://www.linkedin.com/',
  target: '_blank',
  click: function(){ 
    BlahFunc(options.rowId);  
    return false;
  }
}).appendTo('.linkedin-header');
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You're inserting HTML in to the `a` element, not text, so change `text:` to `html:`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's good but how do I overwrite the default code with JQuery ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean?

Comment: With this JQuery function, I would like the content of the div "linkedin-header" to be completely rewritten in JQuery. Currently, the default content is next to the one integrated by JQuery.

Comment: Then delete the default one?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes absolutely ! Sorry for my approximate English...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `text` to `html` :

```
$('<a>',{
  html: '<span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x linkedincolor"></i><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x"></i></span>',
  title: 'Linkedin',
  href: 'https://www.linkedin.com/',
  target: '_blank',
  click: function(){ 
    BlahFunc(options.rowId);  
    return false;
  }
}).appendTo('.linkedin-header');
```

Comment: It's good but how do I overwrite the default code with JQuery ?

Comment: @Pierre-ClémentCazon what do you mean ? It is **already** written using jQuery.